# Eclipse Luna (4.4.2) Keyboard not working

Tags: keyboard

I've just updated my Eclipse Version to Luna 4.4.2 and restarted it.
Now I can not type anything into any text box in Eclipse. In other programs I can type as normal. I have already restart Eclipse and the MacBook.
I've a MacBook Air 2013 with OS X 10.10.3 Yosemite.

best regards
korbi

Answer (score 0):

Probably due to multiple versions of org.eclipse.jface installed. See [Bug 388359](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=388359#c5)

Go to your eclipse/plugins directory and search for org.eclipse.jface_3.** files. In my case found:

1. org.eclipse.jface_3.10.1.v20140813-1009.jar
2. org.eclipse.jface_3.10.2.v20141021-1035.jar
3. org.eclipse.jface_3.8.0.dist.jar

I have moved 1 and 3 out of the directory, leaving only the most recent version. This will work for me.